# Segmentation Fault (singal 11 sigsegv) with linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, cs50

Was writing a program to practice before with linked lists and pointers before pset5 and am left with two memory errors that i have not been able to remedy.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//define struct for Nodes
typedef struct list
{
    int data;
    int key;
    struct list* next;
}Node;

//function declarations
Node* create(int a, int *counter);
void insert(int a, int *counter);
void delete_list();
void printlist();


//global pointers
Node* Head = NULL;
Node* Current = NULL;


int main()
{
    int *keycounter =(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    int value = 20;
    keycounter = 0;
    Head=create(value, keycounter);
    value = 30;
    insert(value, keycounter);
    value = 40;
    insert(value, keycounter);
    printlist();
    delete_list();

    free(keycounter);
    return 0;
}
// VV functions VV
void delete_list()
{
    free(Head);
    free(Current);
}

Node* create(int a, int *counter)
{
    Node* ptr=malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if(!ptr)
    {
        printf("ERROR-NOT ENOUGH MEMORY\n");
        free(ptr);
        return 0;
    }
        ptr->data=a;
        ptr->key=*counter;
        counter++;

        return ptr; 

}

void insert(int a, int *counter)
{
    Node* ptr=malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if(!ptr) {
        printf("ERROR-NOT ENOUGH MEMORY\n");
        free(ptr);
    }
    ptr->data=a;
    ptr->key=*counter;

    //point next field to old head
    ptr->next=Head;

    //assign current node as head of singly linked list
    Head=ptr;
    counter++;
}

//Thank you guys over at tutorialspoint for this neat idea for testing this.
//https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/linked_list_program_in_c.htm
void printlist()
{
    Node* ptr=Head;
    printf("TESTING\n");
    while(ptr != NULL) {
        printf("%p*NODE* KEY:%i VALUE:%i PTR NEXT:%p\n \n", ptr, ptr->key, ptr->data, ptr->next);
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }
}
```

Here is my valgrind output:

[image]

Still learning so alot of the valgrind output is pretty arcane to me and threads on stack exchange regarding the "signal 11 (SIGSEGV)" error are difficult to comprehend as well.

Also, any tips or advice on my code would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to handle the `next` member correctly. Always initialize it with NULL when a node is created and change appropriately when a node is added to a list.

Comment: A good start is to attach a debugger such as `gdb`, then look at the stack trace for where your program crashes.

Comment: Post your code here instead of posting a link.

Comment: Issue is : After malloc your pointer "keycounter" is pointing to valid address but in next line you pass keycounter=0, that point to NULL. i thing it is a typo, you want intilize keycounter with 0, so you should write *keycounter = 0 not keycounter = 0.

Comment: Do not put code on external sites, and [don't put images of code and text output](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) except when it's really necessary. Just copy and paste here

Comment: `total heap usage: 2 allocs, 0 frees, 20 bytes allocated` pretty much says it all. (that's all `valgrind` is telling you) It doesn't address the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem in your code. See the below lines:

```
int main()
{
    int *keycounter =(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    int value = 20;
    keycounter = 0; ===> You are setting the pointer to NULL effectively nullifying the effect of your malloc call above
```

So, in your create function, when you try to access counter, it is leading to NULL pointer dereference

```
Node* create(int a, int *counter)
{
    Node* ptr=malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if(!ptr)
    {
        printf("ERROR-NOT ENOUGH MEMORY\n");
        free(ptr);
        return 0;
    }
        ptr->data=a;
        ptr->key=*counter; ==> Here it will lead to NULL pointer dereference
```

If your `key` member in the struct is just an integer, then no need to pass a pointer (counter is a pointer), you can as well pass an integer and set it.

Comment: Worse than that. Setting a pointer to address `0` is well within the *system reserved memory range* and attempting to access or write to it will guarantee a segfault.